# Microservices architecture best practises

Tags: docker, microservices

I don't know if this is the right platform for this question or not, either way, I am venturing into microservices, have been in for some time though not long and was stuck on the right architecture or rather, best practices:

Which is better and why, having all services of a microservices architecture app inside one docker and running many containers in parallel or having each of those services running in their own docker container (which each docker can be run in multiple instances)?

**P.S.** The services must not necessarily be run using docker

Answer (score 1):

Run each service in a seperate container.

A key aim of microservices is to decouple the release cycles of different components and therefore business units. Using a seperate image per microservice is necessary to do this.

Secondly, Docker containers should ideally only have one process run in the foreground as the orchestrator looks at this process to help manage the container lifecycle. Occasionally ive run secondary processes in the same container for the sake of ease, but it’s better really to set them up as a ‘sidecar container’. Putting multiple services in one container will mean that process monitoring - restarting etc are now your problem rather than the orchestrators problem.

Lastly using seperate containers for each service will allow them to scale independently, so if you need 100 instanced of service A to handle load, you don’t have to run 100 instances of services B, C and D at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

As Docker states in their docs, you are supposed to run each "service" (e.g., PostgreSQL, node.js server, Python server) in their own container so that there is a separation of concerns. This allows better maintainability and lets each container have multiple instances (e.g., 1 instance for the DB and 3 for the server).

These kinds of questions are better suited for the Software Engineering StackExchange site: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/.